# How to save a pc-group in MAGMA?

Tags: group-theory, magma-cas

I have a group $M$, which is a large matrix group. Using the command $\texttt{LMGSolubleRadical(M)}$ I obtained $R\cong M$, where $R$ is of type $\texttt{Grppc}$, and an isomorphism $M\to R$ called $\texttt{map}$. The purpose of this was to conduct calculations which would take too long in $M$. At this stage, I have performed some calculations and have obtained the elements of $R$ that I need -- they are in a set called $R_I$. There are approximately two million of them, and to do what I need to do next, I need to run my calculations in parallel using $\texttt{screen}$ with about 50,000 elements per screen. To carry these out, it is required that they be pulled back into $M$ first. However, if I do this, I cannot save twenty million elements of $M$ because these matrices are so large that I lack the storage space. So, my solution was to store several sets $I_1 ,\ldots,I_{20}$, each containing 50,000 $\texttt{Grppc}$ elements. Then, on each screen I could load $R$, $M$, $\texttt{map}$, and $I_j$ (for some $j$), then do $\texttt{Ij @@ map}$ and thus obtain the matrix set without ever having to save it.

The issue comes when saving the pc-group. When I save the isomorphism $\texttt{map}$, it does not actually save the function. Also, when saving $R$ and loading it again, it does not recognise elements of $R$ as being elements of $R$ in a new screen, even if I coerce them into $R$ before saving them.

I'm at a total loss here -- I've tried several combinations of coercing elements and saving them and so on but nothing seems to work. If I had the function $\texttt{map}$ it would not be a problem. Does anyone know why \textsc{Magma} doesn't seem to save these groups and maps like others? If anyone can think of another way around my issue, feel free to make suggestions.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If all you need to do is to compute inverse images under ${\mathbf{ map}}$, then you could define the inverse of ${\mathbf {map}}$ as an ordinary Magma homomorphism using the images in $M$ of the PC-generators of $R$, and save that. Or, alternatively, just store these generator images and redefine the inverse of ${\mathbf{map}}$ when you reload.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I like the idea of replacing \texttt{map} with an ordinary homomorphism - that was something I failed to try. However, I did try storing the generators of $M$ along with their images but when I loaded them onto another screen I couldn't define a homomorphism between them because the images of the generator were no longer "inside" $R$ (from the point of view of \textsc{magma}) and could not be coerced into $R$ either. Will try your first suggestion though!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the following worked for saving the images of $\mathbb{map}$.

```
  > M, R, map := LMGSolubleRadical(G); 
  > L := [ R | M.i @ map : i in [1..Ngens(M)] ];    
  > PrintFileMagma("mapims",L);
```

Then on re-starting:

```
  > L := eval Read("mapims");
  > R := Universe(L);
  > L[3] in R;
  true
```

To reconstruct the inverse of map, write

```
  >  mats := [R.i @@ map : i in [1..NPCgens(R)]];
```

and save mats. Then after restarting, you can construct the inverse of map by

```
  > imap := hom< R -> Generic(G) | mats >;
```

($\texttt{Generic(G)}$ is the general linear group in which lies, and I put that rather than $G$ so that Magma does not waste time trying to check that the elements of mats lie in $G$.)

Comment: I've tried combining both of your ideas, but unfortunately neither of them actually solve the problem.
Regarding your first idea: I tried defining an ordinary homomorphism between $M$ and $R$ using the generators of $R$, but when I save this, it is saved in a form that is not loadable.
Your second response works, but recall that I'm trying to pull sets $I_j$ back into $M$. Setting $\texttt{R:=Universe(L)}$ and loading $I_j$ means that Magma no longer thinks of $I_j$ as being inside $R$.

Comment: Feel free to e-mail me more details of what you are trying to do with an example that doesn't work.

Comment: Sorry to drag this up again but I never got it to work and had to take a break on it for a while. I'm at the end of my rope.

Comment: Sorry, hit enter too soon... My problem is that defining the universe of $L$ is all well and good but doesn't actually solve the problem. I'm trying to pull my sets $I_j$ back into $M$ which is a matrix group. In my initial setup I had $R$ as type GrpPC, $R$ isomorphic to $M$, and $M$ a large matrix group. I can load say $I_1$ into a new screen then create its universe which is a GrpPC group isomorphic to $M$ but unless I use something like IsIsomorphic (which won't complete as the groups are too big) I can't find any way of getting the elements of $I_1$ back into $M$ because $map$ won't save.

Comment: See my addition to the answer.

Comment: Thanks for all your help with this. Your suggestion seems to work. I was just wondering if you could explain something. The way you define $imap$ uses the set of generators of $M$. How can we be sure that $imap$ is the very same homomorphism by only specifying the generators in the range?

Comment: Sorry, but I am not udnerstanding what you are asking. $M$ is a group of matrices, and $R$ is a PC-group isomorphic to $M$. ${\mathtt{map}}$ is an isomorphism $M \to R$, and ${\mathtt{imap}}$ is the inverse isomorphism $R \to M$. I don't know what you mean by "only specifying the generators in the range".

Comment: Sorry, I'm probably not explaining very well. $\mathtt{map}$ is the original isomorphism $M\to R$, and we create the same isomorphism in a new screen (except we switch the domain and codomain) and call it \texttt{imap}. That's fine, but to create \texttt{imap} we define is as a homomorphism from $R$ to $M$ specified by \texttt{mats}, a set of generators for $M$. How can we be certain that these isomorphisms are the same? Let's say I take $m\in M$, then $r = map(m)$. Are we necessarily guaranteed that $imap(r) = m$? If so, I'm not sure why.

Comment: Sorry, used the wrong code for typewriter font then didn't edit it in time!

Comment: $\mathtt{mats}[i]$ was defined to be the inverse image under $\mathtt{map}$ of $\mathtt{R.i}$, so if we make $\mathtt{imap}$ send $\mathtt{R.i}$ to $\mathtt{mats}[i]$ then we are defining the inverse map to $\mathtt{map}$, which is what we want.

Comment: That's what I thought, but we have to construct $R$ again in a new screen each time by setting it to $R:=\mathtt{Universe(L)}$. I'm pretty ignorant as to how Magma finds things like this -- does building $R$ again this way guarantee that all of its generators are the same and in the same order?

Comment: Well yes, $R$ is a PC-group, and PC-groups are defined by their generators and relations. But even with other types of groups, if you saved a group and then restored it, its generators would be the same as in the version you saved.

Comment: I see, thank you. The issue I'm having now is that mats won't load in a new screen. This might be because these matrices are huge. mats is a 10MB file and it literally will not load in a new screen. Before saving, I can coerce each element of mats into Generic(G) and store them in a set called matsG. This is now about 8MB and will load in a new screen. However, I cannot define the homomorphism $\texttt{imap := hom< R -> Generic(G) | matsG >;}$ because it returns the error: Runtime error in hom< ... >: Bad image for this hom constructor

Comment: I don't think it makes sense to carry on discussing this in a sequence of comments. You should send me an e-mail with full details of the calcualtion and what is going wrong. Incidentally I wrote much of the Magma code for the LMG functions, so I am in a sense responsible!